# Cant't upload file to Firebase. SwiftUI, imagePickerController Error code: 13000

Tags: firebase, video, swiftui, upload, storage

I want to upload a video file to Firebase storage.
This is my code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        guard let uid = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: uid)

        if let url = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
                ref.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }else{
                        print("Succes")
                    }
                }
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

Im getting error:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown
> error occurred, please check the server response."
> UserInfo={bucket=skidays-d2cc1.appspot.com,
> _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <75FCF919-3959-45EC-9C02-50824E91E9AA>.<1>,
> object=jsZqif4oxSUCJHUA1YOlbbCctjh1,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "BackgroundUploadTask <75FCF919-3959-45EC-9C02-50824E91E9AA>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the
> server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skidays-d2cc1.appspot.com/o/jsZqif4oxSUCJHUA1YOlbbCctjh1?uploadType=resumable&name=jsZqif4oxSUCJHUA1YOlbbCctjh1&upload_id=ADPycduSbMdqLIs3k9y0sfgwm0ut8V98dae0HJ5e1Vto_Yt9eWq7Hc_HqQsV-zFE_sX6YDMjG71JzJJyAESn0cGYrubuRQ&upload_protocol=resumable,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/skidays-d2cc1.appspot.com/o/jsZqif4oxSUCJHUA1YOlbbCctjh1?uploadType=resumable&name=jsZqif4oxSUCJHUA1YOlbbCctjh1&upload_id=ADPycduSbMdqLIs3k9y0sfgwm0ut8V98dae0HJ5e1Vto_Yt9eWq7Hc_HqQsV-zFE_sX6YDMjG71JzJJyAESn0cGYrubuRQ&upload_protocol=resumable,
> ResponseErrorCode=-1})